# Disconnect from db created with createConnection

Tags: mongoose

I'm trying to disconnect from a database I connected to with `createConnection`:

```
var conn = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://'+ ip + ':' + port, options);
conn.on('connected', function () {
    new Admin(conn.db).listDatabases(function(err, result) {
        // process data ...

        conn.disconnect();
        res.sendStatus(200);
    });
});
```

But I get the error

```
    /var/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:123
    process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });
                                        ^
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'disconnect'
    at /var/app.js:47:25
    at handleCallback (/var/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:120:56)
    at /var/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/db.js:994:22
    at /var/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:469:18
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:458:13)
```

I also tried `conn.db.disconnect()` which returns the same error.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `conn.disconnect()`, but there is a [`conn.close()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#connection_Connection-close).

There *is* a [`mongoose.disconnect()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-disconnect), but I don't think that'll close connections made with `mongoose.createConnection()`.